# understanding od -a option

Tags: od

In Linux, the `--type a` option in `od` is explained as

> `--type=`
>         Select the format in which to output the file data
>   … 
>   `a` 
>        named character, ignoring **high-order bit**
>   …
>   Only the least significant seven bits of each byte is used; the high-order bit is ignored.

Now [this answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8506/36242) explains a lot, especially "*and words were two bytes long*" – which leads to my specific

**Question**: *What does **high-order bit** mean in connection with "named characters"*

Maybe I'm just missing something…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Named characters" means the output will print the name of a character rather than its numerical ASCII value.  For printable characters, the name used is the actual character and for non-printable the names are things like `nl` for newlines and `sp` for spaces.

The high-order bit is the bit with the highest value.  For single-byte ASCII characters, this bit is the 8th bit whose unsigned value would be 128.  If you ignore this bit, you are left with ASCII values between 0 and 127 and it is from this range that `od` is picking the name of a character.

Comment: Great and very helpful answer. Where did you find this information? (still a Noob trying to figure out stuff myself but often ending frustrated…)